# Position element in ordered list in logarithmic time Python

Tags: python, list, find, position, locate

I have a sorted list and i need to position an element within that list such that the previous element is <= and the next element in the list is > (the list is a list of floating point numbers)

I shall need to return the position of the element that is <= i.e. the previous element

how can i implement this in logarithmic time. i thought of using a method similar to binary seacrh but couldn't get it to work

Any help would be appreciated

P.S. an example is:if the list is

```
testlist=[0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]
```

and i run the function for 0.27
the function will return 1 (the location of 0.25)
and if i run it for 0.5 it'll return 2

Comment: "Couldn't get it to work" - What have you tried?

Comment: If this is homework, you should tag it as such to avoid answers like the one that suggest using the `bisect` module.

Answer (score 3):

There is a dedicated module for binary search: [bisect](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html#module-bisect)

```
import bisect

testlist=[0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]
print bisect.bisect(testlist, .27) - 1
## 1
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer worked, now I can move on with the rest of my code